# Partition by multiple columns written in rows from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have this table:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
| User | Value | Rule1 | Rule2 | Rule3 | Rule4  |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|    1 |    10 |    20 |    14 |    15 |     22 |
|    2 |     5 |    20 |     7 |     8 |     25 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

I want to do a partition by query, like that:

```
SELECT sum(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Rule1, Rule2)
FROM MY_TABLE
```

but i don't want to write "Rule1, Rule2". I want to read a table like

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Rules |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Rule1 |
|  1 | Rule2 |
|  2 | Rule1 |
|  2 | Rule2 |
|  2 | Rule3 |
|  3 | Rule2 |
|  3 | Rule3 |
|  3 | Rule4 |
+----+-------+
```

So i can write something like that:

```
SELECT sum(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY "all rules separated by comma where ID = 1")
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Is it possible? Someone has a better alternative?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get what you want.  What does the vertical table have to do with the original data?  What comma are you talking about?  What results do you want?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The vertical table have the column names from the original table that may be used for partitioning the original table.

Comment: You can't do this with standard SQL. You will need dynamic SQL - generally a sign of very poor design. (What you are describing IS very poor design.) If you've never heard of dynamic SQL, it is probably best not to attempt it on your own. I also don't see much value in someone else writing the solution for you and you taking it and using it without understanding it; it will be impossible to maintain it (or even to test it properly).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       sum(value) over 
           (partition by (case when exists (select 1 from tablelikethis tlt where tlt.id = 1 and tlt.rules = 'rule1') then t.rule1 end),
                         (case when exists (select 1 from tablelikethis tlt where tlt.id = 1 and tlt.rules = 'rule2') then t.rule2 end),
                         (case when exists (select 1 from tablelikethis tlt where tlt.id = 1 and tlt.rules = 'rule3') then t.rule3 end),
                         (case when exists (select 1 from tablelikethis tlt where tlt.id = 1 and tlt.rules = 'rule4') then t.rule4 end)
           )
from my_table t
```

Comment: no.. for example, if my partition is:

SELECT sum(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Rule1, Rule2, Rule3)
FROM MY_TABLE

i want to use something like 

SELECT MY_TABLE.*, sum(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY (select GROUP_CONCAT(Rules SEPARATOR ', ') from second_table where id = 2) )
FROM MY_TABLE

so i don't need to write "Rule1, Rule2, Rule3". Can you understand? It's kind of hard to explain what am I thinking

Comment: @Douglas . . . This does what you describe.